# fs database will not save for some reason?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate a code, add it to a database, and then return it to the request server. I'm getting no errors, but the database remains empty, nothing gets added. I'm using glitch as a temporary host, my json file is just {}

My code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const rbx = require('noblox.js')
const fs = require("fs")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

const client = new Discord.Client()
client.verificationCodes = require("./codes.json")

require("dotenv").config()
const port = process.env.PORT
const serverKey = process.env.SERVER_KEY
const cookie = process.env.COOKIE

function randomString(length, chars) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
}

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Client is ready.")
})

app.post("/getVerificationCode", function(req,res,next) {
    console.log("Recieved")
    if (req.body.serverKey !== serverKey) {
        console.log("Invalid serverKey supplied.")
        
        return res.status(403).json({
            error: "You do not have permission to use this."
        })
    }

    let verificationCode = randomString(4,'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ').toUpperCase()
    const userID = parseInt(req.body.userid)
    console.log(verificationCode)

    client.verificationCodes[userID] = {
        code: verificationCode
    }

    fs.writeFile("./codes.json", JSON.stringify(client.verificationCodes,null,4), err => {
        if (err) throw err
    })

    return res.status(200).json({
        VerificationCode: verificationCode
    })
})

app.get("/*", function(req,res,next) {
    return res.status(200).json({})
})

app.listen(port)
console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)

function rbxLogin(newCookie) {

    try {
        rbx.setCookie(newCookie)
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(`Invalid cookie supplied, or expired. ${err}`)
    }


}

// rbxLogin(cookie)



client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
```

I watched a video on how to use an fs database. I appreciate any help!

Comment: What is in the console from this statement? `console.log(verificationCode)`

Comment: You'll need to clarify this: "_my json file is just {}_" - do you mean when you send a request to your glitch server all you get back is `{}`? If that's the case, that is what you told your server to send back with your `app.get('/*",...)` route.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I get a verification code. What I mean is, when I look in the codes.json file, it's just empty.

Comment: After `if(err) throw err`, add this statement on the next line (within the callback): `console.log(fs.readFileSync("./codes.json", "utf8"));` and report the result please.